# convert the data received from url to json format

Tags: javascript

[image: from $.getJSON I get following data show in figure]

Is it possible to convert the the data shown in figure to following format:

```
Object {glossary: Array[4]}
glossary : Array[4]
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: @S S are you trying to convert to JSON or do something else?  The code block and the image you have are the browser showing you what an object is and what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the browser attempting to show you the structure of the data.  The actual structure is an array of objects as you would write it in code is:

```
[{firstname: "Fozzy", lastname: "The Foz", title: "Garbage Disposal..."}, {...}, {...}]
```

To convert the variable `data` to a JSON string, you would call:

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

This will return:

```
"[{"firstname": "Fozzy", "lastname": "The Foz", "title" : "Garbage Disposal..."}, {...}, {...}]"
```

Comment: I solved using following method:
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'persons.json',
        success: function (data) {          
            data = { 'roles': data }; 
            var html = Mustache.to_html($('#tpl').html(), data);
            $('#car').html(html);

        }
    })